# sql self-join table remove duplicate lines

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
╔════════╦════════════╗
║ USERID ║ LANGUAGEID ║
╠════════╬════════════╣
║      1 ║          2 ║
║      1 ║          7 ║
║      1 ║          8 ║
║      2 ║         10 ║
║      2 ║          3 ║
╚════════╩════════════╝
```

now I want to create all the possible pairs of languages for each user
which means that I want the result set to be:
for user 1: (2,7), (7,8), (2,8)

for user 2: (10,3)

to do so I've done the following query:

```
SELECT a.userId , a.LanguageId, b.LanguageId
FROM knownlanguages a, knownlanguages b  
WHERE a.userID=b.userID  
AND a.LanguageId<>b.LanguageId
```

the result that i'm getting is 
for user 1: (2,7), (7,8), (2,8) ,   (7,2), (8,7), (8,2)

for user 2: (10,3), (3,10)

there is no difference for me between (10,3) and (3,10)

how can I remove the duplicate lines?

tnx

Comment: `WHERE a.userID=b.userID  AND a.LanguageId < b.LanguageId`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

With your identifiers:

```
SELECT a.userId , a.LanguageId, b.LanguageId
  FROM knownlanguages a inner join knownlanguages b  
    on a.userID=b.userID and a.LanguageId < b.LanguageId
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/207d4/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( u int, l int);

insert into t values 
(    1,               2),
(    1,               7),
(    1,               8),
(    2,               10),
(    2,               3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.u, t1.l as l1, t2.l as l2
from t t1 inner join t t2
   on t1.u = t2.u and t1.l < t2.l
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/207d4/1/0)**:

```
| u | l1 | l2 |
|---|----|----|
| 1 |  2 |  7 |
| 1 |  2 |  8 |
| 1 |  7 |  8 |
| 2 |  3 | 10 |
```

Comment: Amazingly clean and simple!  By just adding **`a.LanguageId < b.LanguageId`**, all duplicates are removed.

Comment: I think the use of < in lieu et place of <> is so simple that it should be the first answer to look.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT  userId,
        LEAST(LANG_ID1, LANG_ID2) ID1,
        GREATEST(LANG_ID1, LANG_ID2) ID2
FROM
    (
      SELECT a.userId, 
             a.LanguageId LANG_ID1, 
             b.LanguageId LANG_ID2
      FROM   knownlanguages a, knownlanguages b  
      WHERE  a.userID=b.userID  AND 
             a.LanguageId <> b.LanguageId
    ) s
GROUP BY userId, ID1, ID2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9257/12)

The output,

```
╔════════╦═════╦═════╗
║ USERID ║ ID1 ║ ID2 ║
╠════════╬═════╬═════╣
║      1 ║   2 ║   7 ║
║      1 ║   2 ║   8 ║
║      1 ║   7 ║   8 ║
║      2 ║   3 ║  10 ║
╚════════╩═════╩═════╝
```

or simply,

```
  SELECT a.userId, 
         a.LanguageId LANG_ID1, 
         b.LanguageId LANG_ID2
  FROM   knownlanguages a, knownlanguages b  
  WHERE  a.userID=b.userID  AND 
         a.LanguageId < b.LanguageId
```