# SQL: Remove duplicates in self-join

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I have the following table (called t1):

```
| id | Name    |
| 1  | Charlie |
| 2  | Bob     |
| 3  | Alice   |
```

I want to match the table with itself (self-join) but only choose a combination that has not already appeared. So far, I have the following:

```
select * from t1 a, t1 b
where a.id != b.id
```

which gives me this result:

```
| a.id | a.Name  | b.id | b.Name  |
| 2    | Bob     | 1    | Charlie | 
| 3    | Alice   | 1    | Charlie | 
| 1    | Charlie | 2    | Bob     | 
| 3    | Alice   | 2    | Bob     | 
| 1    | Charlie | 3    | Alice   | 
| 2    | Bob     | 3    | Alice   |
```

I only want an id to appear once from table a, and once from table b. A desired outcome would be:

```
| a.id | a.Name  | b.id | b.Name  |
| 2    | Bob     | 1    | Charlie | 
| 3    | Alice   | 2    | Bob     | 
| 1    | Charlie | 3    | Alice   |
```

But I'm stumped as to how to guarantee this.

I am using SQL Server 2017.

Here's a fiddle with my test: [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b65d29033f381fb8736387a7bdab6706)

PS: I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304928/sql-self-join-table-remove-duplicate-lines) question, but the concept of the solution using a "less than" as a comparison operator isn't clear to me in my own example.

**Edit:** There are no rules as to which pair is chosen; the pairs could be (2,3), (3,1), (1,2) instead of the ones I presented above because the only rules I am interested in is having **only once each id from table a and from table b**, and **a.id != b.id**.

**Edit 2:** There is no logic to match them, please think about it as this possible premise:
I am matchmaking Alice, Bob and Charlie as if they are having a Secret Gift Exchange. They could only offer a gift to one person, could only receive one gift, and could not offer a gift to themselves. (I think this allows scalability)

Comment: What are the rules for deciding which of each pair appears in the result set?  It doesn't appear to be based on alphabetical order of the ID value.

Comment: There are no rules as to which pair is chosen; the pairs could be (2,3), (3,1), (1,2) instead of the ones I presented, because the only rule I am interested in is having only once each id from table a and from table b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option which uses a `ROW_NUMBER` trick to stagger each name with a different name:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM t1
)

SELECT
    t1.Name,
    t2.Name
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON (t1.rn % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte)) + 1 = t2.rn;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

The logic is to just match row number 1 with 2, 2 with 3, and 3 with 1 (we use the modulus to wrap around at the edge case).  This ensures that no name would ever appear more than once in a given column.

Answer (score 0):

OP want to match assign each person a random partner, the solution is not completely random and only works if the IDs are continuous. However, it can be fixed by calling combining random/order_by/row_number

my lazy fix is:

```
select * from t1 a, t1 b
where a.id = b.id % ( select count(*) from t1 c) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me a result of

`| a.id | a.Name  | b.id | b.Name  |
| 2     | Bob        | 1     | Charlie   | 
| 3     | Alice       | 1     | Chalie   | 
| 3     | Alice       | 2     | Bob       |`

which you can see repeats ids both in a and b...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your expected result is. Ain't you supposed to remove duplicate pairs? As you have 3 rows in the database, you can achieve what you have. However, once you have more than 3 rows. What would your expected output?

Comment: As I think of it, I would be expecting to matchmake Alice, Bob and Charlie as if they were having a Secret Gift Exchange. They could only offer a gift to one person, could only receive one gift, and could not offer a gift to themselves. I think this premise allows scalability

Comment: Let's say you have 1,2,3,4 in DB, what would the final result be? (1, 2), (2,3), (3, 4), (4,1)?

Comment: Ah. Got you, but what is the logic to match ID 1 to ID 2? random?

Comment: Yes, the logic is random, I've added it in the question to hopefully make it more explicit :)

Comment: very difficult in SQL with no assumption. can be done if the IDs are continuous. Are they?

Comment: The IDs aren't continuous, but maybe I could always create a third column that would have a continuous number and could act as ID. Don't know how ideal that is though

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`. Then do self join based on row number.

```
select a.id, a.name, b.id, b.name from
    (select row_number() over (order by id desc) rn, id, name from t1) a
join 
    (select row_number() over (order by id asc) rn, id, name from t1) b on a.rn= b.rn
```

Comment: This gives me a row where a.id is equal to b.id. What could I use to prevent that and have the 3 ids paired with eachother?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this.

This partitions the data based on which of the two ids are greater and create a concatenated string (larger_id,'|',smaller_id)

After that i am chosing just one value on the concatenated string by checking 
where rnk=1.

```
with data
as (
select a.id a_id,a.name as a_name,b.name as b_name,b.id b_id
       ,row_number() over(partition by case when a.id>b.id then concat(a.id,'|',b.id) 
                                            else concat(b.id,'|',a.id) end
                              order by b.id desc)
        as rnk
  from t1 a
  join t1 b
    on a.id != b.id
     )
select *
  from data
 where rnk=1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c3f82c8d21dc14899a263adacf1b31e6

Comment: This returns the same a.id matched twice unfortunately